# No logs for Postfix in Docker with rsyslog?

Tags: linux, docker, rsyslog, postfix-mta

I'm building a Docker container from `debian:jessie`.

I've installed `rsyslog` [this normally](https://askubuntu.com/a/394804/135947) causes `/var/log/mail.log` to be created.

However after running some commands with `postfix` I look in `/var/log/` and can't find anything related to mail.

Is there a step I'm missing when using `rsyslog` with Docker?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by running the following after startup:

```
service rsyslog restart
```

*Even though `rsyslog` had been installed it was never started.*